# Lossy png compression

Tags: image-processing, png

What sort of library would be recommended for lossy png compression while retaining alpha layer.

I use kraken.io a lot but would like to work it more into a workflow.

I know a lot about lossless compression but I'm at a loss with how they do lossy.

Comment: as png uses a completely lossless compression algorithm, the only possibility would be "decreasing the quality" of the original image before compressing it. as png uses the zlib method, I guess that bluring will increase the file size, and reducing the numbers of colors will decrease the compressed size.

Comment: @user287107 I would consider a paletted PNG to be lossy.

Comment: @Mark Ransom no, a paletted PNG is not lossy. if you convert a photo to an 8 bit paletted image, that can be lossy. but if there are less colors than the numbers of palette colors, it is lossless.

Comment: @user287107 conversion to palette is equivalent to [vector quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_quantization) which is a classic method of lossy data compression.

Comment: of course the conversion from 24 bit to an 8 bit palette is lossy. but this is a preprocessing before the png compression. png itself is completely lossless, a 24 bit image is just compressed as 24 bit image.

Comment: Not a library, but I seem to recall [MeeSoft Image Analyzer](https://meesoft.com/Analyzer/) experimented with lossy compression techniques on RGBA images, see also https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/8878/115215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG is **lossless** by design, there's no lossy PNG. All you can do is some **lossy preprocessing** before saving it as PNG, as converting a true colour image to a **palette** one, or by reducing the number of colors by **posterize** - all that will probably reduce the size of the image, but that's not part of PNG.

Comment: I am familiar with posterize in photoshop but what about something programmatic?

Comment: Note that those aren't the only techniques for "lossily" compressing PNGs. For instance, despeckling artifacts in a JPEG image might give you a better compression ratio at the cost of possibly improving your image.

Answer (score 3):

If you literally want a library, then [libimagequant](http://pngquant.org/lib) (I think that's what kraken.io uses).

There's also [mediancut posterizer](https://github.com/pornel/mediancut-posterizer) that achieves lossy compression by preprocessing. It's much more effective than posterization in Photoshop or ImageMagick.

[Description of lossy PNG methods on ImageAlpha website](http://pngmini.com/lossypng.html).